# Communicating between VB.NET UI and Java application

Tags: java, vb.net, soap, tcp

I have a VB.Net application with a UI that has to start a Java Application , and receive/read the messages produced by the java application.

What is the best way to establish a communication/link between these 2 processes ? 
I see people recommending SOAP or TCP sockets.

Can somebody suggest tell me how I should proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you need and how you are implementing everything.

You could probably use [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) mechanisms to obtain what you are after. Another option could be to let your processes write instructions to each other to files.

Without knowing anything about the implementation and scope of your application, TCP is usually better (in my opinion) since it is the one which is easier to adapt. Meaning that should one day, your processes need to run on different machines, TCP would provide (as far as I know) the easiest way to transition from one stage (both processes running on the same machine) to the next.

Should you need to send some complex data, then using some framework which rests on TCP, maybe [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Object_Access_Protocol) or [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) would make your life easier.